# Unable to get the correct style, what concept am I missing here?

Tags: html, css

This is the final product, I am trying to get ignore the background color since the background color in the browser is black.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iar68.png)

Here is my trial.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4spHx.png)

Here is my HTML and CSS, please let me know what concepts am I missing and what I should do so that this green container doesn't spread all over. Also,  if I remove inputwrapper, I will get pretty close but not close enough.

Here is my HTML file and here is my CSS file.

style.css

```
  .container {
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 200px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    padding-left: 50%;
    padding-right: 50%;
}

.inputWrapper label {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* .inputWrapper {

    border: 5px solid darkblue;
    width: 300px;
    display:block;
    
} */
```

and index.html file is

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Practice</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="container">
        <div class="inputWrapper">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </div>
        <div class="inputWrapper">
          <label for="age">Age (Years)</label>
          <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Add User</button> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
        width:300px;
        display:block;
        border-radius: 12px;
        padding:20px;
        background-color: green;
        margin:auto;
}
```

Use this in css